How to check if an item of list exists in another list in jolt
In the given input request, check if the request.PartyAlternateId.item.AltIdType.idTyp is equal to existingMDMResponse.PartyAlternateId.item.AltIdType.idTyp, if so then  add existingMDMResponse.PartyAlternateId.item.rowidObject as PartyAlternateId.item.key.rowid to the same item in the output. Repeat this matching to all items in the request.PartyAlternateId.item. And also add the existingMDMResponse.PartyAlternateId.item.rowidObject to the PartyAlternateId.$original.item.rowid in the output. request.id will go as PartyAlternateId.item.key.sourcekey for all the matched items.
Input
{
  "request": {
    "id":"1001",
    "PartyAlternateId": {
      "item": [
        {
          "AltIdType": {
            "idTyp": "0002",
            "idTypDesc": "UCM ID"
          },
          "AltIdVal": "B99857DB-5B3C-469a-A976-F504AA74660A"
        },
        {
          "AltIdType": {
            "idTyp": "0001",
            "idTypDesc": "Account Number OU_NUM"
          },
          "AltIdVal": "104267367"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "existingMDMResponse": {
    "MaskedFlg": false,
    "PartyAlternateId": {
      "link": [],
      "firstRecord": 1,
      "pageSize": 10,
      "searchToken": "multi",
      "item": [
        {
          "rowidObject": "1801667       ",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "B6C6C095-7924-490a-BFF8-325F43921F3A",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20006         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0006",
            "idTypDesc": "Ultimate Sales Account"
          }
        },
        {
          "rowidObject": "1801668       ",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "46C01DCD-64E3-47c5-98B3-E1E0F029EDD9",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20007         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0007",
            "idTypDesc": "Sales Account UCM ID"
          }
        },
        {
          "rowidObject": "1801669       ",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "91109",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20008         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0008",
            "idTypDesc": "Portal Organization ID"
          }
        },
        {
          "rowidObject": "12880622",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "5D4F54B8-5C26-4c61-A73D-6324AEC3951A",
          "EffStrtDt": "2022-02-04",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20002         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0002",
            "idTypDesc": "UCM ID"
          }
        },
        {
          "rowidObject": "12880628",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "158126",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20001         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0001",
            "idTypDesc": "Account Number"
          }
        },
        {
          "rowidObject": "87164         ",
          "label": "Party Alternate Id",
          "AltIdVal": "4683",
          "AltIdType": {
            "rowidObject": "20008         ",
            "label": "Lookup Alternate Id Type",
            "idTyp": "0008",
            "idTypDesc": "Portal Organization ID"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Expected Output
{
  "PartyAlternateId": {
    "item": [
      {
        "key": {
          "sourcekey":"1001",
          "rowid": "12880628"
        },
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTyp": "0001",
          "idTypDesc": "Account Number OU_NUM"
        },
        "AltIdVal": "104267367"
      },
      {
        "key": {
          "sourcekey":"1001",
          "rowid": "12880622"
        },
        "AltIdType": {
          "idTyp": "0002",
          "idTypDesc": "UCM ID"
        },
        "AltIdVal": "B99857DB-5B3C-469a-A976-F504AA74660A"
        
       }
     ],
    "$original": {
      "item": [
        {
          "rowid": "12880628"
            },
        {
          "rowid": "12880622"
             }
       ]
    }
  }
}


Try the following spec:
   [

  {
    //group items from PartyAlternateId & existingMDMResponse
    // under each idType value object where if there is match the same
    // idType value object will host both info and hence we can create
    // the required structure
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request": {
        "PartyAlternateId": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "AltIdType": {
                "*": "PartyAlternateId.item.@(1,idTyp).&",
                "@(4,id)": "PartyAlternateId.item.@(1,idTyp).key.sourcekey"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "existingMDMResponse": {
        "PartyAlternateId": {
          "item": {
            "*": {
              "AltIdType": {
                "@(1,rowidObject)": "PartyAlternateId.item.@(1,idTyp).key.rowid"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //transpose match items to new array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "PartyAlternateId": {
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "key": {
              //if sourcekey found that has rowid then move to the new array
              "sourcekey": {
                "@(1,rowid)": {
                  "@(3)": "PartyAlternateId.item[]",
                  //move matched items rowid to the original array 
                  "@": "PartyAlternateId.\\$original.item[].rowid"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ]

